# Axon Partialy replay, how do i get a TrackingToken for the startPosition for the replay?

Tags: axon, replay

I want my Axon replay events, not all but partially.
A full replay is up and running but when i want a partially replay i need a `TrackingToken startPosition` for the method `resetTokens()`, my problem is how to get this token for the partial replay?

I tried with `GapAwareTracingToken` but this does not work.

```
    public void resetTokensWithRestartIndexFor(String trackingEventProcessorName, Long restartIndex) {
        eventProcessingConfiguration
                .eventProcessorByProcessingGroup(trackingEventProcessorName, TrackingEventProcessor.class)
                .filter(trackingEventProcessor -> !trackingEventProcessor.isReplaying())
                .ifPresent(trackingEventProcessor -> {
                    // shutdown this streaming processor
                    trackingEventProcessor.shutDown();
                    
                    // reset the tokens to prepare the processor with start index for replay
                   trackingEventProcessor.resetTokens(GapAwareTrackingToken.newInstance(restartIndex - 1, Collections.emptySortedSet()));
                    
                    // start the processor to initiate the replay
                    trackingEventProcessor.start();
                });
    }
```

When i use the `GapAwareTrackingToken` then i get the exception:

```
[] - Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incompatible token type provided.]
```

I see that there is also a `GlobalSequenceTrackingToken` i can use, but i don't see any documentatieon about when these can/should be used.

Comment: You say "does not work". Could you elaborate on that? What happens exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main "challenge" when doing a partial reset, is that you need to be able to tell where to reset to. In Axon, the position in a stream is defined with a TrackingToken.

The source that you read from will provide you with such a token with each event that it provides. However, when you're doing a reset, you probably didn't store the relevant token while you were consuming those events.

You can also create tokens using any `StreamableMessageSource`. Generally, this is your Event Store, but if you read from other sources, it could be something else, too.

The `StreamableMessageSource` provides 4 methods to create a token:

- `createHeadToken` - the position at the most recent edge of the stream, where only new events will be read
- `createTailToken` - the position at the very beginning of the stream, allowing you to replay *all* events.
- `createTokenAt(Instant)` - the most recent position in the stream that will return all events created on or after the given `Instant`. Note that some events may still have a timestamp earlier than this timestamp, as event creation and event storage isn't guaranteed to be the same.
- `createTokenSince(Duration)` - similar to `createTokenAt`, but accepting an amount of time to go back.

So in your case, `createTokenAt` should do the trick.

Comment: if i understand correctly, we need to keep track of the tokens our selfs in oder to replay from a certain event?

Comment: Either that, or use one of the methods described to create one based on a timestamp